# python git-submodule importing from other git-submodule

Tags: python-3.x, git-submodules, python-module

Using Python 3.6
I did create multiple modules (like DBmanager or jsonParser etc which I use across multiple different python projects)

For simplicity: I have created a module, lets call it 'gitmodule03'.
Internally it is supposed to be using yet another module from github 'gitmodule01' for parsing data. I have added 'gitmodule01' to 'gitmodule03' by

```
'git submodule add http://git/gitmodule01'
```

Separatenly, I am developing my 'MainPackage' which will use directly 'gitmodule03' and 'gitmodule01' (among others). I've added them all to my main Program with

```
'git submodule add http://git/gitmodule01'
'git submodule add http://git/gitmodule02'
'git submodule add http://git/gitmodule03'
```

and my package looks like this:

```
.
└── MainPackage
    ├── modules
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── gitmodule01
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── mymodule01.py
    │   ├── gitmodule02
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── mymodule02.py
    │   ├── gitmodule03
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── mymodule03.py
    │   │   └── gitmodule01
    │   │       └── 
    │   └── mymodule04.py
    └── myMainProgram.py
```

**At this moment 'gitmodule03' is NOT importing 'gitmodule01' internally**. I was hoping that importing it in main myMainProgram.py would propagate across submodules (which is not the case)

If my **myMainProgram.py** imports them all:

```
from modules.gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
from modules.gitmodule02.mymodule02 import my02class
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
```

my03class() # will work

my02class() # is internally using 'my03class()' and will error out:

***NameError: name 'my03class' is not defined***

How can I design those so they can work independently as well as within bigger package, in clean, pythonic way ?

*I would like to have those modules idependent so they won't have to use any hard coded **sys.path()*** methods

**Edit Test Cases:**

1.

```
myMainProgram.py
sys.path.insert(0, "modules/gitmodule03/gitmodule01/")
from mymodule01 import my01class
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
my01class() #works
my03class() # NameError: name 'my01class' is not defined
```

2.

```
myMainProgram.py
from modules.gitmodule03.gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
my01class() #works
my03class() # NameError: name 'my01class' is not defined
```

3.

```
mymodule03.py
from gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
my01class() #works

myMainProgram.py
from modules.gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
my03class() # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gitmodule01'
```

4.

```
mymodule03.py
from .gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
my01class() # ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.gitmodule01'; '__main__' is not a package

myMainProgram.py
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
my03class() # works
```

With Test Case #4 It looks like i could make myMainProgram.py work but i would have to break module on its own.

Comment: Which python version are you running, python2 or python3? How are you importing `gitmodule01` from `mymodule03`? If you are using implicit relative imports (python2) then it is obvious that this breaks the code...

Comment: @Bakuriu Python 3.6. Currently I am asking myself that question - how should I import? atm not importing there at all. I was hoping that importing gitmodule01 from myMainProgram.py would propagate and would be available across every submodule. But if that is not the case, maybe I should add nested submodule to mymodule03 and import it there again by .gitmodule01/.mymodule01 ?

Comment: I don't know. Personally, I believe you are completely wrong with the whole setup. Ditch `git submodule`. Develop your various models separately and use `virtualenv`s. I believe using `git submodule` is just way harder than necessary and I don't see the benefit. In fact in the couple of projects I've worked that used it it soon became a pain in the ass when I incorrectly commited a submodule update that should nothave been committed..

Comment: @Bakuriu, thx for suggestion! Those submodules are my wrappers, like jsonParsing module or DBmanager module which i use across multiple projects. I was hoping that I could develop them separately and update with git to all my projects

Comment: @Bakuriu, I will definitely test virtualenv approach. As for committing submodules by accident, yeah, had same issues but I found solution for this - you have to add "ignore = dirty" to .gitmodules file.

Comment: Using a submodule in git in no way removes the need to do your Python imports properly. I agree with @Bakuriu that you should just write your modules as standalone libraries with the proper dependencies and let pip or whatever handle your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I could not find better option to have both working myMainProgram.py and  mymodule03.py on its own.
At the moment I am checking **name** variable to see whenever module is working on its own or whenever it is run from other package:

```
mymodule03.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class
    my01class() # works
else:
    from .gitmodule01.mymodule01 import my01class

myMainProgram.py
from modules.gitmodule03.mymodule03 import my03class
my03class() # works
```